# Unable to use line tension for scatter chart with 'showLine' enabled

Tags: vue.js, vue-chartjs

I'm trying to chart a time scatter plot using vue-chartjs but am having trouble getting the line tension to work. If I set the tension option for the data set to anything but 0 the line disappears.

The chart data and options (just some dummy data for now):

```
    const chartOptions = {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: true,
        plugins: {
            legend: false
        }
    };

    const chartData = ref({
        datasets: [
            {
                data: [
                    { x: 0, y: 5 },
                    { x: 3, y: 4 },
                    { x: 5, y: 7 },
                    { x: 8, y: 13 },
                    { x: 13, y: 6 },
                    { x: 18, y: 2 },
                    { x: 25, y: 11 },
                ],
                backgroundColor: "#ED1369",
                borderColor: "#ED1369",
                showLine: true,
                tension: 0,
                pointRadius: 3.5,
                pointHoverRadius: 3.5,
                borderWidth: 2
            }
        ]
    });
```

Result with no tension (tension: 0):
[Chart showing lines with no tension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMnPm.png)

Result *with* tension (tension > 0):
[Chart breaking and no longer showing lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOcVq.png)

I've tried using both "tension" and "lineTension" options, as well as the "cubicInterpolationMode" option. I have also tried various combinations of those options. I have tested and found that Chart.js does support curved lines on scatter plots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you have to register the *Filler* component.

https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs/issues/988

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33567984)